# What is the difference between watcher.dart and observe.dart?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

These two libraries, `watcher.dart` and `observe.dart` seems to provide very similar functionality. Why are they both part of the `web_ui` package?

Can I use and include them directly, or only through inclusion of the `web_ui.dart` library?

I have tried to include `observe.dart` in my project and it broke both one-way and two-way data-bindings. Is there any reason for such a behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `watcher.dart` library is slowly being phased out. Using observers is now the recommended way of creating one-way and two-way data bindings. For the time being, both `watcher.dart` and `observe.dart` are being supported, but don't rely on support for `watcher.dart` continuing in the future.

For examples on how to use observers, see http://www.dartlang.org/docs/cookbook/#web-ui.

Comment: Wow, that is great. Also, do you have any explanation, why I can't actually include the observe.dart?